# Prove that column indices of pivot columns of a matrix in reduced row echelon form are always greater than row indices

Tags: linear-algebra

I am self-studying linear algebra from the book *A First Course in Linear Algebra* .

This is part of a question I am struggling with :

Suppose that $B$ is a matrix in reduced row-echelon form that is equivalent to the
augmented matrix of a system of equations with $m$ equations in $n$ variables.Prove that $d_k\geq k$ for all $1\leq k\leq r$.

$r$ is the number of nonzero rows 
$d_k$ is the pivot column index

It seems intuitive to me, but I don't know how to formulate a proof. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This basically translates to "all the pivot _entries_ lie on or above the diagonal". Maybe that's a little more obvious?

Comment: Yes,thanks. That made it more clear.